# Overriding variable in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have problem with following code:

```
v_background.assign(
   tf.cond(tf.less(candidate_mse, mse),
   lambda: resp,
   lambda: v_background)
 )
```

Basically what I want to happen is when candidate_mse is lower than old mse, v_background will be overridden with resp, otherwise it stays the same. Issue is when I call

```
v_background.eval()
```

it seems to have initial value regardless of mse.

```
print(mse.eval())
print(candidate_mse.eval())
```

Results with

```
0.0314396114956
0.031410553229
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates the assignment operation, but doesn't actually run it. If you want to do one-time assignment, just run the operation.

```
assign_op = v_background.assign(
   tf.cond(tf.less(candidate_mse, mse),
   lambda: resp,
   lambda: v_background)
 )
 sess.run(assign_op)
```

If you want a value that switches between the two depending on the values `candidate_mse` and `mse`, use `tf.where`.

```
v_background = tf.where(tf.less(candidate_mse, mse), resp, v_background)
sess.run(v_background)
```